# Proper way to set up react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My question is very simple: What is the proper/standard way of setting up a `react-router`? I heard some people saying it is best/cleanest to make a separate file such as `router.js` and include all the routes in that file. However, it seems like some `react-router` tutorials do not follow that convention (Well, I don't know if what I heard is a convention).

Maybe I'm understanding this totally wrong. If I am, please correct me.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a matter of your needs, your app's scale/structure, and your preference.

Comment: Maintaining separate router file is the best way to understand easily and fix the routing issues quickly if any will face in future.

Comment: @isherwood Hmm... What is the most effective way in your opinion?

Comment: The entire point of my comment is that we can't possibly know without knowing those aspects of your project and your dev team.

Comment: aha, I understand. Thanks for answering!